# In MySQL, how do I insert 1 when string value is 'true', 0 when false, while preserving nulls

Tags: mysql, boolean, insert-into, string-conversion

I am using an `INSERT` query that `SELECT`s from a plain-text database into a more query-friendly database.  The following is simplified a lot to prevent confusion with unnecessary information, if I've simplified too far for clarity please let me know and I will amend.

Source data appears as follows:

```
    |    id (integer)    |    SomeCol (varchar)    |    BooleanCol (varchar)   |    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |    1               |    'String Data'        |    'true'                 |
    |    2               |    'Other Data'         |    'false'                |
```

The target table needs to look as follows after my `INSERT` query:

```
    |    id (integer)    |    SomeCol (varchar)    |    BooleanCol (tinyint(1))   |    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |    1               |    'String Data'        |    1                         |
    |    2               |    'Other Data'         |    0                         |
```

I'm looking for something that would work more or less like this, borrowing a bit from java syntax:

```
    INSERT INTO target(SomeCol, BooleanCol) 
    SELECT SomeCol, (BooleanCol IS NOT NULL ? (BooleanCol == 'true' ? 1 : 0) : null) 
    FROM source
```

Note that the java syntax provided as an example of what I want is intended to preserve `null`s as needed.

Also, while I'm here, if you happen to know how `SELECT` the current time stamp from MySQL that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mysql has an IF operator which is similar to the ?: operator in most languages. `IF(cond, val_if_true, val_if_false)`

```
INSERT INTO target(SomeCol, BooleanCol) 
SELECT SomeCol, IF(BooleanCol IS NOT NULL , IF(BooleanCol = 'true' , 1 , 0) , null) 
FROM source
```

Comment: Worked out for me as well in UPDATE.